# ITK installation error using Cmake

Tags: cmake, itk, cmake-gui

I am trying to install/configure ITK using Cmake, but unable to do it as there are errors which I am unable to resolve. Could some one please help?
Also why is the location set to C:/Program Files (x86)/ITK? Please help!

[image: Cmake Screen]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The C++ compiler is not found. Have you Visual Studio installed or some other compiler? (1: Screenshots are a bad idea, it's better to copy the error message into the question. 2: `C:/Program Files (x86)/ITK` is the CMake install prefix, that means that the program will be installed below this directory if you call the install target. If you do not intent to install your own ITK, this doesn't matter).

Comment: It seems that code at `CMakeLists.txt:18` calls `enable_language(C++)`, which is incorrect: correct language for C++ compiler is `CXX`, like [here](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt). Probably, your ITK sources are corrupted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could solve it. The Visual Studio compiler for 2015 is:
Visual Studio 14 2015

Comment: This doesn't the answer the question for other people with the same problem. I'd close this question nevertheless, because it does not seem helpful to me.